# How to show the variable values at the top of the table in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, html-table, jstl

I am passing an object from servlet to jsp and then I am iterating that object in the jsp and showing the results in a table as shown below. And while iterating the table, I calculate some counts and store it in a variable.

These are my count variable -

```
kCount
rCount
totalCount
```

And then I am showing the actual values of these count variables in `fieldset` as shown below and it works fine.

```
<div>

    <!-- if I try to show the fieldset here, then I see all the values coming as zero. -->

<TABLE>
    <TR>
        <TH>VALUE1</TH>
        <TH>VALUE2</TH>
        <TH>VALUE3</TH>
        <TH>VALUE4</TH>
    </TR>

    <c:set var="kCount" value="0" scope="page"/>
    <c:set var="rCount" value="0" scope="page"/>
    <c:set var="totalCount" value="${CV.getValue().size()}" scope="page"/>

    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${CV.getValue().size() - 1}">
        <TR>
            <TD>
                ${CV.getValue().get(i)}
            </TD>
            <TD>
            ${CV.getHasR().get(i)}
            <c:if test="${CV.getHasR().get(i) == 'True'}">
                <c:set var="rCount" value="${rCount + 1}" scope="page"/>
            </c:if>
            </TD>
            <TD>
            ${CV.getType().get(i)}
            <c:if test="${CV.getType().get(i) == 'K'}">
                <c:set var="kCount" value="${k + 1}" scope="page"/>
            </c:if>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </c:forEach>
</TABLE>

    <!-- I don't want to show the fieldset here, it should be shown at the top of the table -->
    <fieldset>
        <legend><b>Window</b></legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>VALUE2</th>
                <th>VALUE3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total rows:</td>
                <td>${totalCount}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>R Count:${rCount}</td>
                <td>K count:${kCount}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Now If I try to copy this fieldset and try to show at the top of the `table` instead of showing at the bottom of the table, then I see all the values as zero. My main goal is to show the values of each variables in the fieldset but it should be shown at the top of the table, not at the bottom.

Any thoughts how this can be one if possible at all?

Comment: you may create another `for` loop specifically for that purpose

Comment: @RafaEl: hmm.. Is there any other way apart from for loop you are suggesting?

Comment: Generally, JSPs should be used for presentation.  Calculations and other business logic usually belong in the servlet.  You could calculate the values you need there and pass them as additional variables to the JSP.

Comment: @akiiddweeber djmorton is definitely correct.

Comment: You could use Javascript function and css :P beacuse if u can do calculation on jsp, u can do it too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three options here (I am sure there are many more):

1. Calculate your totals in the servlet and pass them to the JSP for display
2. In the JSP, loop through your data first to calculate the totals and display them, then loop again to display the data
3. In the JSP, loop through and display your data while calculating your totals, then use jQuery or similar to write the totals back into the correct location using javascript.